# How do I prove this in the opposite direction?

Tags: complex-numbers

**Prove that $\frac{1}{x}=\bar{x}$ if and only if $1=|x|$**.

Here's what I have so far:

$\bar{x}$ is the conjugate of $x$. Multiplying both sides of $\frac{1}{x}=\bar{x}$ by $x$ yields $1=x \cdot \bar{x} = -x^2$.

Taking the square root of both sides $1=-x^2$ can be written as $1=|x|i$.

Am I on the right track? If yes, what should I consider from here? If not, what should I reconsider? Thank you!

Comment: No. $x\bar{x}=|x|^2$.

Comment: What is the connection with the title ?

Answer (score 2):

Note that $x\cdot\overline{x}=|x|^2\neq -x^2$, so you can instead proceed from here by just taking square roots. You can then prove this in the opposite direction by reversing your previous steps

Comment: Taking square roots isn't required here, and anyway taking square roots of complec numbers is a minefield of errors...

Comment: @5xum the modulus is a real number....

Comment: Yeah, but $x$ and $\overline x$ aren't...

Comment: @5xum I only took a square root of the modulus?

Comment: So, you only took the square root of one side of an equation? How does that work?

Comment: $\sqrt{|x|^2}=\sqrt{1}$. I don`t see the problem? @5xum

Answer (score 2):

For $x\ne 0$,

$$\frac1x=\bar x\iff1=x\bar x\iff1=|x|^2\iff1=|x|$$ (last equivalence because $|x|$ is known to be positive).

Answer (score 1):

We have $$\frac {1}{x} = \bar x $$ $$\Rightarrow \frac {1}{x}(x) = \bar x (x) $$ $$\Rightarrow 1 = x \bar x = |x|^2$$

May I let you conclude? Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

$\Rightarrow$ Assume that $\frac{1}{x}=\overline{x}$. Then $1=x\overline{x}$. Thus, 
$$|x|^2=x\overline{x}=1.$$ This implies that $|x|=1$.

$\Leftarrow$ Assume that $|x|=1$. Clearly, $x\neq 0$. Then
$$x\overline{x}=|x|^2=1,$$ and we get $$\frac{1}{x}=\overline{x}.$$